# Need help with a specific part of a planimetry exercise

Tags: geometry, triangles

The Excercise goes as follows:
I have $2$ - $4$ sided figures, $ABCD$ and $ADCM$.
$M$ is the centre of the circumscribed circle of $ABCD$ with $DB$ being its diameter.
additoinally, $ABD$ is defined as $42 ^\circ$ and $EC$ has the same length as $EM$.
Calculate the angle of $CAD$

I was able to calculate most of the lower angles but I just can't figure out how to calculate any of the upper ones.  I know I have to use the identical lenght of EM and EC, but the only ifnormation that gives me, is that EMC is a same sided triangle.

Can anybody makes sonse of all this? I just kind of seams like I have no idea how to get one of the uppre angles using one of the lower ones.

[image: The excercise]

Comment: If you found some of the angles, tell us which ones you found and what their angular measures are.

Comment: I found MAB=42, AMB=84, EMA=96, DAM=42

Comment: One piece of advice is to try to find some way to organize your calculations so you can do them correctly, because you have wrong values for $\angle AMB,$ $\angle EMA,$ and $\angle DAM.$ Note that the three angles of $\triangle AMB$ should have sum $180,$ and you should have $\angle DAM+\angle MAB=90.$ By avoiding errors in these intermediate calculations you would have a much easier time completing problems like this correctly.

Comment: Yeah I just relized my mistakes, and found the correct values, I accidentally used 46 as the inital value: DAM=48 AMD=84 ADM=48, but I still can't figure out how to calculate the upper angles

Comment: OK, those values are correct, so you just need a couple more steps as shown in the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $EC=EM,$ triangle $\triangle CEM$ is isoceles,
and $\triangle AMC$ is isoceles because two of the side are radii
of the circle.

From $\triangle CEM$ we get $\angle ECM=\angle EMC.$
From $\triangle AMC$ we get $\angle MAC=\angle MCA.$
Also observe that because $E$ is on the line segment $\overline{AC},$
we have $\angle ECM=\angle MCA.$

So we have several angles that are all the same size. So that we don't
get confused by all the names referring to different locations in the
figure, let the size be $\alpha.$ That is, we have
$$\angle ECM=\angle EMC=\angle MCA=\angle MAC=\alpha.$$

Now consider the triangle $\triangle AMC$ again.
One of its angles is $\angle MAC=\alpha,$ one is $\angle MCA=\alpha,$
and the third is $\angle AMC = \angle AME+\angle EMC=\angle AME+\alpha.$
The three angles of an triangle must have sum $180,$ so
$$
\alpha + \alpha + (\angle AME+\alpha) = 180.
$$
You can find $\angle AME$ as an exterior angle of the isoceles
triangle $\triangle AMB$ or as the measure of the arc of the circle
intercepted by the inscribed angle $\angle ABD.$
Then solve for $\alpha.$

Finally, use the fact that $\angle CAD+\angle CAM+\angle MAB=\angle BAD=90,$
so knowing the measures of $\angle CAM$ and $\angle MAB,$
find $\angle CAD.$

Comment: gives me 16, which is exactly the soluition, thanks a lot, I sat on that for almost an hour.

Answer (score 2):

$EC=EM;MC=MB$ $$\therefore \angle ECM=\angle EMC=\angle MBC+\angle MCB=2\angle MCB$$Now $$\angle DCA(=42^\circ)+\angle ECM+\angle MCB=90^\circ$$

So $$\angle CAD=\angle MBC=\angle MCB=16^\circ$$

Comment: I'm afraid I don't entirely understand how you got from EC=EM;MC=MB to ∴∠ECM=2∠MCB, also why is cad equal to mcb?

Comment: @user2741831 $\angle ECM=\angle MCB+MBC$

Comment: @user2741831 Please dont hesitate to ask more questions. NO question is silly.. I will hep you..

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't follow, I don't see the connection between these 3 angles.  Could you tell me the name of the rule you are referncing?

Comment: Hint: try to explain a little bit more your solution. If a kid is starting in geometry, he gets a bit longer to understand everything. +1 anyway.

Comment: @user2741831 Okay.. Wait. I am editing my answer

Comment: @user2741831 You understand the first set of equations?

Comment: partially, I understand why ECM and EMC and MBC and MCB are eqaul (ss traingle), but I don't understand why MCB+MBC are equal to EMC, and I also dont understand why mcb is equal to cad, since there doesn't seam to be any paralel lines in the figure

Comment: @user2741831 Have you learnt that **In a triangle, an _exterior_ angle is equal to the sum of _opposite interior_ angles** ?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't think about using that rule, I'll have a second look at your picture with that in mind, thnaks